# How to retrieve information of people who committed code into SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol

Am actually planning to retrieve user-ids of people who committed code recently into SVN repository. This would help me in sending an email to all such users who recently committed code in case if the build fails.

We are using CruiseControl for build and Tortoise SVN for comitting the code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Cruisecontrol will do this automagically for you.

You have to use the [`<svn>` definition](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#svn) and [`<email>`](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#email).

Have a look at the `<map>` attribute of email to set the email adresses for the users.

> Maps a source control user id to an email address.

Comment: How i can find out only Tortoise SVN?